# PlacePicker in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-place-picker

I am following [PlacePickerAPI](https://github.com/AndroidCodility/PlacePickerAPI)

The issue is to place picker opens and closes suddenly. I have found one of the answers on StackOverflow and also done as below :

1. Enabled Places API in Google console.
2. I have added API key in AndroidManifest file as below :

Is PlacePicker is deprecated? If yes, What might be the solution for this issue?
Is there any support provided for Google Place Picker in Kotlin?

What might be the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Please look for any errors throw in the LogCat and post them here, the clue is probably in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Place Picker is deprecated as of January 2019, This feature is turned of on July 2019 and will no longer be available after this date for Android and iOS.
The main reason was due the new pricing model of the **Places API**.

For more information check this: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlacePicker

You can check alternative here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

You can get demo for New Places SDK from here: https://github.com/nihas/NewGooglePlacesAutocomplete

Comment: What the alternative for it?

Comment: I have to select location dynamically. picking the place dynamically and have to get latlng.

Comment: You can migrate to places sdk. see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit in answer. Can I get the place picker with Map as it was there in older Place Picker ?

Comment: Yes You can implement it by your own with new sdk or check this https://github.com/rtchagas/pingplacepicker